# confusion in variadic template

Tags: c++

While exploring variadic templates, I found that recursive function could be with and without template but now my code is as below and I wondering why the `add()` is not called and neither the compiler throws any warning.

```
//why this one is not called   
void add(){
    std::cout << "[]";
}

template <typename T>
void add(T x){
    std::cout << x << "{}";
}

template <typename T, typename ...ARGS>
void add(T x, ARGS ...a){
    std::cout << x << ":";
    add(a...);
}   

int main()
{
  add(3.1, 3.4, "6.7", 4u, "7.54");
  return 0;
}
```

Also when I comment `add(T x)`, the `add()` is called. I am confused.

Answer (score 2):

Trace through the code one step at a time.

```
add(3.1, 3.4, "6.7", 4u, "7.54")
```

Here, we print 3.1 and then call

```
add(3.4, "6.7", 4u, "7.54")
```

We print 3.4 and call

```
add("6.7", 4u, "7.54")
```

Again, we print 6.7, then call

```
add(4u, "7.54")
```

We print 4 and then call

```
add("7.54")
```

Now the single-argument overload gets called. The single-argument overload simply prints 7.54 and *doesn't* call `add` again. It's likely you simply forgot to call it that final time.

```
template <typename T>
void add(T x){
    std::cout << x << "{}";
    add();
}
```